# .toDateString without the 'Day name'

Tags: javascript, date

I am using this code to get the date into a span with id 'today'. However now requirements mean I need to take the actual day of the week out of the line. So just 14 Sep 2018 (for example?) Is there a way to achieve this without spelling out the whole date.

```
$('#today').html(d.toDateString());
```

Comment: use a library like moment.

Comment: `d.toDateString().substring(4)`

Comment: Salman A had the perfect answer. Can you explain what it did. It took the 4th string from the line?

Comment: @conye9980 just check out the documentation on substring

Comment: @conye9980 It returns the string starting at the 5th character (zero based index - removes characters 0-4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) method returns the date portion of a Date object in human readable form in American English.

You can split the string with empty string then rearrange the string in the way you want:

```js
var d =  new Date().toDateString(); //Fri Sep 14 2018
d = d.split(' ');                   //["Fri","Sep","14","2018"]
$('#today').html(d[2] + ' ' + d[1] + ' ' + d[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="today"></span>
```